# Restoring bitlocker drive dd image

Tags: boot, encryption, dd

I did a whole disk backup with dd of a Windows drive protected with Bitlocker. I switched the drive to a bigger drive (256GB to 1TB) and now trying to restore with dd. So far, it looked fine since I see the partitions when I boot a Linux live USB stick but I am unable to boot normally. It ask me for the Bitlocker recovery key which I have. It then goes in "Preparing automatic repair" and then it goes on a blue Bitlocker screen that ask to "Enter the recovery key to get going again". The recovery key ID is good, the drive label too ! Then it says "unlocking" and "diagnosing your pc". Afterward, it goes in an "automatic repair" screen with offers me to restart or some advanced options. Restarting brings me at the beginning and I'm now clueless with what to do.

Thanks for any guidance !

[precision] Couple days later, I tried disabling TPM and was able to go farther in recovery mode. It even detected my old username and was able to log in the recovery mode. It is now "attempting repairs" for a while.

Answer (score 0):

When you did a backup of the drive, it was protected with bitlocker encryption and the backup was also protected with bitlocker so suggest if you can please remove the bitlocker encryption from the drive before making a backup then you won't face any problem booting up the drive.

Comment: Problem is : I can't boot the old drive and remove bitlocker. Also, it would take forever to unlock/copy/relock on the new drive. I am looking for an easy way to boot the new drive. There sure is a way but I can't seem to figure out. Again, I feel like i'm close since the new drive boot to a "Bitlocker recovery" screen. So it detects successfully the partition.